# Unable to read hive table content after writing the same through spark shell in hdp 3.0.1 using hive warehouse connector

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hdp

I have written table in hive using hive warehouse connector. But I am unable to read  the content of the same after writing. Below are the details of commands used:

Commands to write the data:

```
hive.createTable("sales_22feb").ifNotExists().column("userid","string").column("ordertime","string").column("saleamount","string").column("orderid","string").create()

val df= spark.read.csv("/tmp/sales.csv")

df.write.format("com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseConnector").option("table", "sales_22feb").mode("append").save()
```

Commands to read data:

```
val hive = com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseBuilder.session(spark).build() 

hive.setDatabase("default")

val df=hive.executeQuery("select * from sales_22feb")

df.show(5,false)
```

Getting below error:

```
20/06/25 16:43:54 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4, sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com, executor 1):java.lang.RunTimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: hive.llap.daemon.service.hosts must be defined
```

However I am able to see contents of the same using hive shell. Kindly help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set  "spark.hadoop.hive.llap.daemon.service.hosts" to the name of the llap daemon in spark-defaults.conf or pass using --conf.

For example:
If llap daemon is @llap_LlapCluster, you need specify it as below in spark-defaults.conf :

```
spark.hadoop.hive.llap.daemon.service.hosts @llap_LlapCluster
```

Answer (score 0):

From HDP 3.X onwards reading/writing internal hive table is supported via **Hive Warehouse Connector (HWC)** framework.

When ever you are writing to hive table **Hive LLAP Service** is not required.

When ever you are reading from hive table **Hive LLAP Service** is required. Check the below documentation for configuring spark HWC.

https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/integrating-hive/content/hive_configure_a_spark_hive_connection.html